# Getting strings from TkInter entry widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm a newbie in Python and I'm trying to create a GUI using TkInter. The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to display the entry text. Below are the two functions that I have made for this task. Is there something missing in my code?

This is my first function where I created the entry widgets:

```
def getArea():

  x1 = StringVar()
  x2 = StringVar()
  y1 = StringVar()
  y2 = StringVar()

  #coor x1
  labelX1 = Label(input, text="X: ").grid(row=1, column=1)
  entryX1 = Entry(input, width=8, textvariable=x1).grid(row=1, column=2)
  #coor x2
  labelY1 = Label(input, text="Y: ").grid(row=2, column=1)
  entryY1 = Entry(input, width=8, textvariable=y1).grid(row=2, column=2)
  #coor y1
  labelX2 = Label(input, text="X: ").grid(row=1, column=3)
  entryX2 = Entry(input, width=8, textvariable=x2).grid(row=1, column=4)
  #coor y2
  labelY2 = Label(input, text="Y: ").grid(row=2, column=3)
  entryY2 = Entry(input, width=8, textvariable=y2).grid(row=2, column=4)

  x1.set("Defalut value x1")
  x2.set("Defalut value x2")
  y1.set("Defalut value y1")
  y2.set("Defalut value y2")

  coorx1 = x1.get()
  coorx2 = x2.get()
  coory1 = y1.get()
  coory2 = y2.get()

  button = Button(input, text='ok',command=lambda:  showResults(coorx1,coorx2,coory1,coory2)).grid(row=1, column=5)

  exitButton = Button(input, text='exit', command=input.destroy).grid(row=2,column=5)

  input.mainloop()
```

This is my second function where I want to display the strings:

```
def showResults(x1,x2,y1,y2):
showInfo = Tk()
showInfo.title("Location Temperature")
showInfo.geometry("270x100+470+320")

print x1, x2, y1, y2

info1 = Label(showInfo, text=x1).pack()
info2 = Label(showInfo, text=x2).pack()
info3 = Label(showInfo, text=y1).pack()
info4 = Label(showInfo, text=y2).pack()

buttonClose = Button(showInfo, text='exit', command=showInfo.destroy).pack(side= RIGHT)
showInfo.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get the error when i pres the "button" to open the other window, it doesnt show anything, just the "default values". I try to do this without this "default values" and i didn't get anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are many things that need fixing with your code. The first of which is you're creating two instances of `Tk`. Tkinter is designed such that you should only ever create one instance of that class, and call the `mainloop` of that instance exactly once. If you need a second window, create an instance of `Toplevel`.

Second, you don't need to use `StringVar`s. I know a lot of examples on the internet use them, but strictly speaking you don't need them. As a rule of thumb, you only need those if you are going to set a trace on them or if you are going to have two widgets share the same variable (which is actually a pretty cool feature). Instead, you can call the `get` method of a text widget to get the value. The main advantage to this is simply that you have fewer objects that you need to create and manage.

So, what you could do is one of the following:

1. you can save a reference to each of the entry widgets in either a global variable or an instance variable (if you switch to using an object oriented style of programming),
2. you can pass in the reference to the widgets to your `showResults` function.
3. you can continue to use `StringVar`s, and have both the entry widget and the label in your `showResults` function share the same `StringVar`s. Again, you'll need to either store those in a way that the two functions can use them, or pass them from one function to the other.

For an example of the second -- passing references and using the `get` method -- you would do something like this:

```
button = Button(input, text='ok',command=lambda:  x1=entryX1, y1=entryY1, 
    x2=entryX2, y2=entryY2: showResults(x1,y1,x2,y2)
...
def showResults(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    info1 = Label(showInfo, text=x1.get())
    info2 = Label(showInfo, text=y1.get())
```

This isn't the only way, or even the best way. The point is, there's no mystery here. Like with variables used by more than one function, you either need to keep a global reference somewhere, or you need to pass a reference around. Or, you leverage the special properties of the `textvariable` attribute.

Comment: Old post, I know, but I'm hoping you can help. Is there a way to "name" each widget for use later? Say I query a list of 10 funds, and each needs their own text box. This needs to be dynamic as this list can change. I want to loop through each one created and grab the value associated with it.